# Are there any starter kits that uses all of : ASP.Net MVC 1.0 with Nhibernate. Sparkview, Jquery, Jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, jquery-ui, spark-view-engine

I am looking for a starter kit that already is set up with the following?

ASP.NET MVC 1.0
Jquery/Jquery UI/JqGrid/
Sparkview engine
NHibernate

Code quality is important as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) is probably going to be the closest thing you are going to find in terms of what you're looking for, however it doesn't use the Spark View Engine (not to say it couldn't).

Answer (score 1):

I second S#arp Architecture. Take a look at their google groups, they've recently got a very good starting project (from framework users): http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/. If you need jquery/jqGrid for CRUD then I (shamelessly) advertise my solution: http://sprokhorenko.blogspot.com/2009/12/dedicated-to-my-wife.html. It's yet to be updated with lot of fixes and latest features, and is not very well organized (so it's not a "solution"), but the article itself explains how you can get very convenient CRUD out of jqGrid + MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the link. WhocanHelpme is a good example and code seems to be good. But I am looking for sparkview engine and a smaller code base to sstart with.

Comment: I doubt that you can find _exactly_ what you need. But it's very easy to extend either S#arp or the example with additional libs. In particular, Spark is _very_ trivial to add to MVC. Your best bet is to take whatever has most features and just add those few missing ones.